# imgPath - FileNotFoundException was unhandled

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

I have this problem:

I need to get a little `gif` out of my folder called *beelden*.

This is the code i use:

```
this.afbeelding = Image.FromFile("beelden/" + imgPath);
```

I always get this error:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled beelden/Verdediger.gif

This is my map structure:

- beelden (contains my images (`gifs`))
- SpaceInvaders (contains all project data and classes)
- Spaceinvaders (this is the solution)

*Edit* I still get the same error, whatever I try. This is a school project and has to be done tonight. Been struggeling with it for 2 days now :s.
[image]

**This is another error i get when i change the backslash. Its keeps saying ';' ')'expected. No matter how many times I add it**
[image: error]

Comment: You´re using a forward slash instead of backslashes.

Comment: I think it has to be something simple, but i can't figure it out :(

Comment: @user2416488, remove the forward slash from folder `beelden/`, it should be `beelden`.

Comment: @Habib I did, I used your code, still the same problem :s.
so strange!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) to concatenate multiple segments.

```
Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("beelden", imgPath);
```

In your current code probably the forward slash is causing a problem. You can also try to keep the path in a separate string variable and see the value you get. Try that path in windows explorer to see if the file exists.

EDIT: *(Based on the screen-shot)*, you should replace the forward from the folder name so your statement should be :

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, "beelden" + imgPath)
                                                            //^^^^^^^^^
                                                            //Remove forward slash
```

Comment: If i use this code, the error from that line goes away, but i get another error because we deleted the 'this.afbeelding'.

Comment: @user2416488, where are you deleting `this.afbeelding" ? did you remove it from the code.

Comment: Yes because I tried your code:
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, "beelden" + imgPath)

Comment: @user2416488, I am not really sure what is going on. Please put this line: `this.afbeelding = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine("beelden", imgPath));`. Not really sure why you removed `this.afbeelding`

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute, not relative path. Your folder "beelden" is obviously mapped to another path.
Something like

```
this.afbeelding = Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\beelden\" + imgPath);
```

Or use `System.IO.Path.Combine` together with `Application.ExecutablePath`

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, @"beelden\" + imgPath)
this.afbeelding = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Don't use forward slash for folders (look at the exception message)

Comment: If i delete the slash it still doesn't work. Can maybe someone look at my file? This ahs to be done tonight for school :s.

Comment: You have to replace it with backslash, not simply delete it. Look at the code in my answer.

Comment: If i replace the slash i get another 'error' wich says ';' ')' expected. I doesn't go away if i add those things. Look in the picture ive added